# How to get historical currency data in Google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I use this formula to get the currency:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD", "price", DATE(2006,10,2))
```

But when I enter a date before 2006-10-2 I get an error.

Is there any way to get older data when it comes to currencies?

Comment: It is reproducible if you enter a date before 2000 something, then there is no result coming.

Comment: Yeah, I was not specific enough in my question from the start. So the answer is correct if you look at my question, but then I made a comment about it under the answer. That I wanted to get even older data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought that there might be a cap on historical data, based on some variant of ten years, e.g. rolling quarterly, since your last available date was 1 October 2006.

I checked for myself, for the same forex pair mentioned, Euro to $US. Using this formula in Google Spreadsheet, I had no problem retrieving pre-2006 data (50 historical data points for Euro to $US, in chronological order:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD";"all";"1/23/2005";"50")
```

Comment: Ok, so I have a followup question, how do I get only one data entry. When I change "50" to "1" I get an error. And when I set the value "2" I get 1/24/2005 as the single response, and not 1/23/2005 as I entered.

Comment: And with this formula the history ends at 3/1/2000, so still not all the way back. I actually need 90's as well (not for EUR but for other currencies).

Comment: Yes, I'm also trying to get a single date, without headers. Any way to do that?

Comment: @Ze'ev you can use `INDEX` function to get a single field, for example `INDEX(GoogleFinance(...), 2, 5)`. Documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242